# Multi language store view - Review stars is not visible on product page

Tags: magento-1.8

When switching to other languages the review stars is not working. How can I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reviews and ratings are saved at store view level.
You need to edit each review and associate it to all store views.

Comment: any script for this please? or database query?

Answer (score 0):

Review for all store views:

- Export all rating_id of rating_store table. Add store_id to each rating_id. You can do it manually using the editor Sublime (Select all lines and using Ctrl+Alt+L do edit all lines at once)
- Insert back into the table. Example of SQL:

  INSERT IGNORE INTO `review_store` (`review_id`, `store_id`) VALUES

  (9,1),
  (9,3),
  (9,4),
  (9,5),
  (9,6),
  (9,7),
  (9,10),
  (9,11),
  (9,12),
  (14,1),
  (14,3),
  (14,4),
  (14,5),
  (14,6),
  (14,7),
  (14,10),
  (14,11),
  (14,12),
  ...

On Magento Admin:

- Setup rating for the new store view. ( Catalog > Manage Ratings > Click on each rating and setup the rating visibility for each store)
- On the list of all reviews, select all "Approved" reviews, and change status to "Approved" ( this is just to save the reviews and generate the rating summary)